# Верстка одностранички или логический кошмар

Tags: структуры, ajax, html, логика, css

Ребят, сам себе вырыл яму, но переделывать времени нет.

1. **Дано**: одностраничный сайт. Переход
       между контентом происходит с помощью
       якорей. Якоря рабочие для ввода в
       адресную строку, для сохранения в
       закладки и т.п.
2. **Пути перемещения (пример)**: жмем в меню "Каталог", нас перемещает к якорю... Видим каталог, там есть меню категорий. Тыкаем категорию "1", нас перекидывает в категорию "1". Внутри каждой категории есть еще одно меню (выбор контента)...
3. **Задача**: Я хочу чтобы при выборе контента "АБВ" в последнем меню на странице категории, рядом с меню появлялось описание этого "АБВ". То есть получается на странице категории у нас есть две колонки: сайдбар с выбором контента и бокс с контентом.
4. **Логика**: Главная+Каталог = одна страница (часть 1). Каталог+Категории=одна страница (часть 2). Категория  "1"+контент "АБВ"= одна страница (часть 3). Все вместе = одна страница... ).
5. **Логика (путь)**: - Каталог - Категория - Меню с выбором контента+контент.
6. **Проблема**: Если последнее меню сделать как вкладки, то привязать якоря НЕ получится, а точнее, якоря не будут отображаться в адресной строке.
7. **Ради чего**: Ради сохранения плавности анимации. Параллакс он такой.
8. **Как это выглядит**: Основное меню с выбором "главной" и "каталога" всегда присутствует, где бы мы ни были. Меню с выбором категорий (якорь "Каталог") присутствует только в Каталоге. Меню с выбором позиций категории (якорь Категория "1") присутствует на странице категории. Контент при выборе позиции отображается, допустим, справа от меню позиций. + "хлебные крошки", если глубина >1 якоря.
9. **Что нужно**: сделать страницу последнего якоря (категория "1") в двух колонках, где вторая колонка отвечает за якоря позиций.
10. **Примерный код (без CSS и ajax'a, вам это не надо)**: http://jsfiddle.net/5ecas/1/
11. **Что приходит в голову**: может быть вынести позиции на один уровень с каталогом и категорией? Пока единственное решение, но я никак не могу догнать как бы сделать, чтобы еще и меню выбора позиций было с выделенным выбором.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Нынешнее положение:** переделал структуру. По сути, перевернул вверх
       ногами. Я хотел, чтобы часть якорей
       просто индексировалась (переход до
       категории), а другая часть загружала
       позиции. Теперь я эти части
       поменял местами. Через аякс всё
       подгружается до входа в категорию, а
       в категориях все подгружается через
       анкоры (индексируемые аяксом).
2. **Получается:** 5 страниц (файлов) основных + страницы категорий + навигация по категории через анкоры (позиции выводятся через анкоры).
3. **Выглядит:** как одностраничка.
4. **PROFIT!**